# How to use a string to set iloc in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I understand the general usage of iloc as follows.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4,5],[4,5,6,4,5],[7,8,9,4,5],[10,11,12,4,5]])
df_ = df.iloc[:, 1:4]
```

On the other hand, although it is a limited usage, is it possible to set iloc using a string?

Below is pseudo code that does not work properly but is what I would like to do.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4,5],[4,5,6,4,5],[7,8,9,4,5],[10,11,12,4,5]])
df.columns = ["money","job","fruits","animals","height"]
tests = ["1:2","2:3", "1:4",  "1:3, 4"]
for i in tests:
    print(df.iloc[:,i])
```

Is there a better way to split the string into "start_col" and "end_col" using a function?

Comment: What is the purpose of requiring a string? Doesn't this work perfectly well with integers?

Comment: One purpose is to provide a slice range as an argument to argparser.  
e.g.   test.py --slice "1:2"

Comment: Just for knowledge, I want to know if it's possible or not.

Comment: Something like `t = tuple(map(int, "2:3".split(":")))` to make `t == (2, 3)`. Then `df.iloc[:, slice(*t)]` should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4,5],[4,5,6,4,5],[7,8,9,4,5],[10,11,12,4,5]])
df.columns = ["a", "b", "c" , "d", "e"]

def args_to_list(string):
    strings = string.split(",")
    column_list = []
    for each_string in strings:
        each_string = each_string.strip()
        if ":" in each_string:
            start_ , end_  = each_string.split(":")
            for i in range(int(start_), int(end_)):
                column_list.append(i)
        else:
            column_list.append(int(each_string))

    return column_list
    
tests = ["1:2", "1,2,3,4", "1:2,3", "1,2:3,4"]

for i in tests:
    list_ =args_to_list(i)
    print(list_)
    print(df.iloc[:, list_])
    print(list_)
```

Answer (score 0):

You an just create a converter function:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4,5],[4,5,6,4,5],[7,8,9,4,5],[10,11,12,4,5]])
ranges = ["1:2", "2:3", "1:4"]


def as_int_range(ranges):
    return [i for rng in ranges for i in range(*map(int, rng.split(':')))]


df.iloc[as_int_range(ranges),:]

    0   1   2  3  4
1   4   5   6  4  5
2   7   8   9  4  5
1   4   5   6  4  5
2   7   8   9  4  5
3  10  11  12  4  5
```

Answer (score 0):

`iloc[ ]` is for slicing numeric data. For String slicing, you can use `loc[ ]` like you have used `iloc[ ]` for numbers. Here is the official pandas documentation for implementing `loc[ ]` https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html

Comment: Sorry for the poor wording in my question, but your answer ".loc" is not the answer I'm looking for.